# After exiting custom startup shell script, exit into default startup shell?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, ubuntu

You have to excuse me if I use the wrong language here of if I'm asking an obvious but that is, after all, why I'm here.

I'm just getting to grips with shell scripting and have written a small script that is "Run as a custom command instead of my shell" to make things a little easier for the things I might want to do. Here's what I've got.

```
#
# Custom console startup script.
#

path_to_scripts=~/Scripts

echo "Hello $USERNAME, what would you like to do?"
echo "Options:"
echo "-l        Continue in local machine"
echo "-s        Connect to server"

read response

case $response in
    "l")    echo "Contunie within local machine.";;
    "s")    $path_to_scripts/connect_to_server;;
    *)      echo "Invalid command. Exiting.";;
esac
```

So my terminal starts up with this script and if I select 's' it runs the 'connect_to_server' script fine and connects then I'm in!

However when I enter an invalid command, or key in 'l' to exit and continue as normal the console says 'The child process exited normally with status 0.'

I know that it has just quit and the script has exited but **what I want to do is just run the default shell so that I am then in my local machine at ~, as if id just started up console with default settings.** What do I need to run in order to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `exec "$SHELL"` to replace the current process with your normal shell.

Comment: So as an additional question, I've noticed that also simply running `$SHELL` does, seemingly, the same thing. Is there any reason why you chose this particular way of running it? Or was it just entirely arbitrary?

Comment: Running `$SHELL` directly leaves the script and its associated interpreter running in the background, waiting; using `exec` makes sure that it ceases to exist.

Comment: Excellent, I knew there would be some background reason! Thanks for the quick response.